# How to create a rule to conditionally send a notification email, based on field value?

Tags: rules, entities, emails

In the Article content type, I have a field called "Assign to" which is a reference to a User entity. So that the users (editors) can know witch articles are assigned to them by the administrators.

How should I configure the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to send an email to editor when article is assigned to an editor, telling editors witch article is assigned to them, and who assigned this article?

Comment: *"Finally if it's possible to make the template"* sorry, we can't develop a whole functionality for you. We can answer questions, but here you are closer to giving specification and waiting for solution, than to asking a precise narrow question to get precise, direct answer.

Comment: Yes sure I do not need that you develop for me the code but I'm wondering if my question can be done with rules module!
I'll change the question maybe I have explain badely :)

Comment: I have edited the post now, hope is more specific this one :)

Comment: I edited it a bit for you and retracted my vote to put your question on hold. Of course if my edit is not exactly right, feel free to correct it, just keep the same "spirit", OK?

Comment: No, your edit is fine, and it's the same what I want to say, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of a rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format), which will send an eMail to the userid selected via the field `field_article_reviewer` (= a field I added to my "Article" content type that is defined as an entity reference to a 'user'), and this whenever content of content type "Article" is saved:

```
{ "rules_notify_editor_about_outstanding_review" : {
    "LABEL" : "Notify editor about outstanding review",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_presave--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_article_reviewer" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "[node:field-article-reviewer]",
          "subject" : "Article waiting your review",
          "message" : "[node:author] has submitted a new Article post waiting your review.\r\n\r\nYou can review it at: [node:edit-url].",
          "from" : "[site:current-user:mail]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If (before importing this rule in your environment) in the above exported rule you'd change the field `field_article_reviewer` to match with your field name of the editor, you should be pretty close to getting it to work.

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.